# How to disable gnome fallback animations?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic, animations

Opening an application from the panel starts with fade in and ends with a black square in compiz mode. In 2D-mode launcher on panel starts with border at the edges of the screen, which appears on the second. How to disable it?

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out today. The old way using gconf doesn't work, the old key for `/apps/panel/global/enable_animations` doesn't even exist anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I found this by utter luck using dconf-editor:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/interface/enable-animations
```

Comment: It works until the next reboot. Do you know how can I make it permanent on 13.10 with Gnome desktop? Thanks.